# capistrano 3.5 execute task how catch non zero result

Tags: deployment, task, capistrano

The following task is in a deploy.rb which execute two shell scripts on the server.

```
task :setup_nginx  do
  on roles(:app) do
    execute "sudo /usr/local/sbin/setup_nginx.sh"
    execute "sudo /usr/local/sbin/ctl_nginx.sh restart"
  end
end
```

How can I check if one of these script fails (returns a non-zero value) and take apropriate action? What I want to do is to stop the execution with an error message.

Answer (score 1):

As you probably know already, `execute` will automatically raise an exception and halt the deployment if it detects a non-zero exit status. This behavior is usually "good enough", as long as you always expect commands will execute successfully, and any failures mean something very bad has happened.

However, if you are not sure whether a command will succeed or fail, and you would like to gracefully handle failure cases, then use `test` instead of `execute`.

`test` will return a boolean based on the exit status. If the exit status is zero (i.e. successful), it will return `true`; for non-zero it will return `false`.

For example:

```
task :setup_nginx  do
  on roles(:app) do
    if test "sudo /usr/local/sbin/setup_nginx.sh"
      # do something on success
    else
      # do something different on failure
    end
  end
end
```

Documentation:

https://github.com/capistrano/sshkit/blob/master/EXAMPLES.md#make-a-test-or-run-a-command-which-may-fail-without-raising-an-error

> The `test()` command behaves exactly the same as execute however will return false if the command exits with a non-zero exit (as `man 1 test` does). As it returns boolean it can be used to direct the control flow within the block.